# How to forbid a key from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

Seems like a no brainer but I can't figure how to add a constraint to forbid the existence of a key in Joi, please how do I do this.

```
    const data = {foo: 'xyz', bar: '123'};
    const schema = {
        foo: Joi.string(),
        // how do i forbid bar
        bar: Joi.forbid()
    };
    
    const { error } = Joi.object(schema).validate(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `forbidden`: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2#anyforbidden

```
const schema = {
    a: Joi.any().forbidden()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple delete the key from the object :

**1st Method :**   `delete data.bar`

**2nd method :**  `{bar,...schema}=data`